# Microsoft Azure Mobile Service Javascript Custom API executes db stored procedure permission issue

Tags: api, azure-mobile-services

I have the following custom api function for HTTP GET, the permission is allowed for everyone:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.service.mssql;
    mssql.query('exec dbo.spTest',
    {
        success: function (result){
            request.respond(statusCodes.OK, result);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
        }        
    })
};
```

This is my stored procedure, very simple one:

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.[spTest]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tmpTest Table(BrandName VARCHAR(255))
    INSERT INTO @tmpTest
        SELECT BrandName FROM dbo.tblBrands WHERE [_key]=105
    SELECT BrandName FROM @tmpTest  
END
```

If I run it on DB, it works. [I login DB as administrator]
But custom API cannot execute this SP, even there isn't any error message, the result variable is an empty array:"[]".

Then I change my SP to

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.[spTest]
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT BrandName FROM dbo.tblBrands WHERE [_key]=105
END
```

it selects directly from table instead of using table variable, it works.

Because custom API connects DB with its own user account, instead of admin user, I guess this API account does not have enough permission to declare table variable. I also tried temp table, it does not work either.

Anyone knows solution for granting custom API user permissions? Thank you

**UPDATE**:

Forget about the DB side, even the following script does not work in API:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.service.mssql;

    mssql.query('declare @ttt Table(NAME VARCHAR(255)); insert into @ttt values (\'Jack\'); select * from @ttt;',
    {
      success: function (result){
        console.log("success");
        request.respond(statusCodes.OK, result);
    },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log("error is: " + err);
    }        
})
```

};

Declare a table variable or temp table won't raise error, but any operation on them [select, insert, update] will get exception and request return is just an empty array[]. In the log, there is only "success" recorded. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITTED:
Ah, this has to do with the Temp table - you can just use `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning of your sp - this prevents done_in_proc messages from being sent back while the temp table operations are still happening. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

Your new SP looks like:

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.[spTest]
AS
BEGIN
    -- Suppress RowCount done_in_proc messages emitted from insert
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @tmpTest Table(BrandName VARCHAR(255))
    INSERT INTO @tmpTest
        SELECT BrandName FROM dbo.tblBrands WHERE [_key]=105
    -- Enable rowcount done_in_proc messages going forward and enabling rowcount meta
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    SELECT BrandName FROM @tmpTest  
END
```

ORIGINAL RESPONSE:
Hard to say without having access to the DB, but could it be a schema permission issue? Generally, there is a new schema created with the name of your Mobile service. The service account that AMS creates doesn't have permission to the [dbo] schema. You can grant permission to the schema (not a good security practice, or put the sp under the schema created by AMS. I was able to repro something like you issue with:

```
EXECUTE AS user = 'ivZJMJrfRDLogin_MyAMSUser';
select * from dbo.TodoItem;
```

This returned:

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TodoItem', database 'MyAMS_db', schema 'dbo'.
```

(fyi - I futz with some names to obfuscate my server/database/user names).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added AMS user as a member of 'db_owner' and I also grant it as dbo schema. It did not work. Actually there isn't any permission related error message. I also do some other quick test, please have a look my updated question

Comment: You are right, I should SET NOCOUNT ON in the SP. 
I was not aware that custom API will catch those done_in_Proc messages along with result set. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Do you know when custom API catch those done_in_Proc messages, how to read that how many rows affected in the result? Thanks

Comment: You can put the SET NOCOUNT OFF statement right before the select statement you actually want to return results for. I'll edit my comment with that suggestion, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I find the explanation of my issue from another thread in site: [/azure-mobile-services-custom-api-update-ouput-followed-by-select-returns-empty/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531734/azure-mobile-services-custom-api-update-ouput-followed-by-select-returns-empty/28441292#28441292)

Simply speaking, there are two results returned by query, one is from insert operation on table variable and another is from select operation on table variable. Well custom API just gets the first empty return from insert operation. Please refer to **carlosfigueira**'s explanation for solution.